# Java regexp to remove Freemarker interpolation tags

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regexp to remove Freemarker interpolation tags in a String. I've a template with text and interpolations as `"Hi customer, we remember your appointment ${date?string["dd"]}"`

I want remove/replate this interpolation tag that is a bit particular because has inside the question mark.
I tried to create the regexp in this way:

```
String myString = "Hi customer, we remember your appointment ${date?string["dd"]}"

myString = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("${date?string[\"dd\"]}"), "xx");
```

but don't works. Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: I personally don't know how to fix your RegEx, but you can always test RegEx patterns here https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to assign return value of `replaceAll` method to original string as `replaceAll` (or any other `String` API) doesn't change the underlying immutable String object:

```
String myString = "Hi customer, we remember your appointment ${date?string[\"dd\"]}";

myString = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("${date?string[\"dd\"]}"), "xx");
//=> Hi customer, we remember your appointment xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, you could do:

```
String myString = "Hi customer, we remember your appointment ${date?string[\"dd\"]}";
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\$\\{date\\?string\\[\"dd\"\\]\\}", "xx");
```

The result string is:

```
Hi customer, we remember your appointment xx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dividing string into 4 logical groups and then assembling required content together.

Try following regex:

```
(.*?)(?:\$\{.*?\"([^\"]+).{3})(.*)
```

Example:

```
String text = "Hi customer, we remember your appointment ${date?string[\"dd\"]}";
String replacement_text = "xxx";

String rx = "(.*?)(?:\\$\\{.*?\"([^\"]+).{3})(.*)";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(rx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);
String result = regexMatcher.replaceAll("$1" + replacement_text + "$3");

System.out.println(result);
```

Code will emit:

```
Hi customer, we remember your appointment xxx
```

However, if you want to extract content of marker i.e. `dd`, simply replace value of `replacement_text` with `$2` and you'll get

```
Hi customer, we remember your appointment dd
```